# Echo array value

Tags: php, loop, query

I have following query to store data for last week entries in database:

```
for ( $i; $i <= 7; $i++ ) {
    $val[$i]= $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COUNT(`order_total`) AS  'Total' FROM vm_orders WHERE DATE = CURDATE()-$i" );
}
```

When I `print_r( $var )` I get:

```
Array (
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [Total] => 1
        )
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [Total] => 0
        )
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [Total] => 0
        )
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [Total] => 0
        )
    )
    [5] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [Total] => 0
        )
    )
    [6] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [Total] => 0
        )
    )
    [7] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [Total] => 0
        )
    )
)
```

For each Loop , echoing result as Array Array...

Now the question is, How can I store value in a array. Because I need to pass this to plot graph. I'm new to Programmming. Any suggestion would , help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to have the `print_array($var)` provide an array of values, then you need to change the database function from `$wpdb->get_results` to `$wpdb->get_var`.

You are retrieving just one value from the database, so `get_var` is the function which will return that specific value directly.

Edit:

You can create a comma separated list from the above array using `implode(',', $val)` which can later be passed to any other variables.

`$values = implode(',', $val);
$result = '(' . $values . ')';`

Comment: I need to store those value in a array, for further use. Is there any way.

Comment: If you use the above method, `$var` will have an array of values? Please mention what is shows now. Also can you please change your question and mention how exactly the array should be as per your requirement?

Comment: After your Suggestion, print result is Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) I want store result as $result= ('1','0','0');

Comment: So this is an array of values. I am not sure how it does not answer your question. Can you please explain?

Comment: FYI, the result you have shown is not an array. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Sorry For making it complex. I don't know how to use above print result value . And I want result, to be as similar as $result=('1','0','1'). I actually need to plot graph. So later would be easier for me . If can suggest me, any possible solution.

Comment: Check my edited answer. If you still can't make a variable out of it, then it is no more a wordpress question. The query part was originally related to wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You could leave the query the same and just do this within your loop:

```
for ( $i; $i <= 7; $i++ ) {
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COUNT(`order_total`) AS  'Total' FROM vm_orders WHERE DATE = CURDATE()-$i" );
    $val[$i]= $result[0]->Total;
}
```

Comment: When the CMS provides a function to achieve the result, one should make full use of that. So even though your approach will work, it's not a suggested one.